# Создание своей ns зоны с помощью bind9

Tags: dns, bind, ns

Переходим на другое доменное имя запросили создание соответствующей зоны , использую bind9
Настройки ниже.53 порт открыт , но при проверке любым сервисом пишет что сервер не найден
`named-checkconf` ничего не пишет
Настройка зоны:

```
    $ORIGIN .
$TTL 36000  ; 10 hours
domain.ua.      IN SOA  smtp.domain.ua. root.smtp.domain.ua. (
                2021083001 ; serial
                43200      ; refresh (12 hours)
                14400      ; retry (4 hours)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
            NS  ns.smtp.domain.ua.
            NS  ns.secondary.net.ua.
            NS  ns2.trifle.net.
            NS  smtp.domain.ua
            A   xx.xx.xxx.xxx
            MX  20 smtp.domain.ua.
            TXT "v=spf1 ip4:xx.xx.xxx.xxx a mx ptr include:domain.ua ~all"
            SPF "v=spf1 ip4:xx.xx.xxx.xxx a mx ptr include:domain.ua ~all"

$ORIGIN domain.ua.
xx.xx.xxx.xxx       PTR m
            PTR bd
            PTR ns
            PTR new
            PTR www
```

Настройки named.conf.default.zone

```
zone "domain.ua." {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/domain.ua.zone";
    check-names fail;
    allow-update { any; };
    allow-transfer { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
};
```

Результат `dig -t ns @f.gtld-servers.net. domain.ua.`

```
 ; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.6-Ubuntu <<>> -t ns @f.gtld-servers.net. domain.ua
    ; (1 server found)
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47867
    ;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 1
    ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
    
    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;domain.ua                   IN      NS
    
    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    .                       518400  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
    .                       518400  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
    
    ;; Query time: 186 msec
    ;; SERVER: 192.35.51.30#53(192.35.51.30)
    ;; WHEN: Fri Sep 24 00:35:46 EEST 2021
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 250
```

Результат `dig -t ns @c.root-servers.net. domain.ua.`

```
 ; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.6-Ubuntu <<>> -t ns @c.root-servers.net. domain.ua
    ; (1 server found)
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22664
    ;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9
    ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
    
    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
    ; COOKIE: 06e8dc83fa0cc2d53d5b5e0e6150ac8800cb1be961ef7438 (good)
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;domain.ua.                    IN      NS
    
    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    ua.                     172800  IN      NS      pch.ns.ua.
    ua.                     172800  IN      NS      in1.ns.ua.
    ua.                     172800  IN      NS      ho1.ns.ua.
    ua.                     172800  IN      NS      cd1.ns.ua.
    
    ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
    cd1.ns.ua.              172800  IN      A       194.0.1.9
    ho1.ns.ua.              172800  IN      A       195.47.253.1
    in1.ns.ua.              172800  IN      A       74.123.224.40
    pch.ns.ua.              172800  IN      A       204.61.216.12
    cd1.ns.ua.              172800  IN      AAAA    2001:678:4::9
    ho1.ns.ua.              172800  IN      AAAA    2001:67c:258::1
    in1.ns.ua.              172800  IN      AAAA    2604:ee00:0:101::40
    pch.ns.ua.              172800  IN      AAAA    2001:500:14:6012:ad::1
    
    ;; Query time: 39 msec
    ;; SERVER: 192.33.4.12#53(192.33.4.12)
    ;; WHEN: Sun Sep 26 20:23:20 EEST 2021
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 318
```

Comment: ну, для начала приложите вывод `$ dig -t ns @f.gtld-servers.net. domain.com.` (подставив, естественно, актуальное значение вместо `domain.com.`)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin добавил

Comment: судя по ответу, tld вашего домена — отнюдь не `com.`. вероятно, `net.`. тогда вместо бесполезного вывода приложите вывод запроса к одному из серверов, перечисленных в ответе от `f.gtld-servers.net.`: `$ dig -t ns @c.root-servers.net. domain.com.` (опять подставив актуальное значение вместо `domain.com.`)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin добавил

Comment: ну а теперь опросите все четыре полученных ns-а (`pch.ns.ua.` и далее по списку) на предмет `smtp.domain.ua.`. начните тоже с запроса ns-записей. если сообщат разную информацию, не сообщат никакой, сообщат отличающуюся от того, что вы указали в первом листинге — разбирайтесь и устраняйте.